# Grails: trouble displaying data from a related table

Tags: grails, controller

I have two tables: Hotel and Content

The Content domain looks like this, hotelId is being generated:

```
class Content {

Hotel hotel
String imageUrl

static constraints = {
   imageUrl nullable:true
}
```

I am uploading images to S3 from the Hotel's show page to the related Content table, this is working - now I want to display the images from my content table to the show page of the related hotel object (where the id of hotel = hotelId from content).

I've been at this for a few days and this is what I feet is the closest to correct:

HotelController:

```
def showContent() 
{
    def content = Content.findByHotelId( hotel.params.id )
    render content: content
}
```

Hotel view:

```
<g:if test="${content.hotelId}" action="showContent">
     <img src = "${content.imageUrl}" />
</g:if>
```

This code results in the error of:
'Cannot get property 'hotelId' on null object'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just wondering about this funtion: findByHotelId. Are you sure that this is correct. In my view there should only be a findByHotel()

Comment: No I'm not sure that findByHotelId is correct, however I have just tried with findByHotel and I'm experiencing the same error. It's definitely something small like that though which is wrong

Comment: Hotel hotel = Hotel.findById(params.id)

def content = Content.findByHotel( hotel)

I ment like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick to the standard scaffolding show action in `HotelController`:

```
def show(Hotel hotel) {
        respond hotel
}
```

Then for each content in hotel `show.gsp`:

```
<g:each in="${hotel.contents}" var="content">
    <img src = "${content.featuredImageUrl}" />
</g:each>
```

I guess you'll want to wrap each of the above in a div or style it somehow.

Comment: Thank you, but this is still returning the same error as before, 'Cannot get property 'hotelId' on null object'

Comment: Does the content domain you're trying to render have an associated hotel? Try `<g:if test="${content?.hotelId}">`

Comment: Yes it does. Hotel with an id of 1 is linked to Content who's HotelId is 1 and so forth. Adding the '?' loaded the page without throwing an error but nothing was included on the page

Comment: Nothing as in blank page or just no image with link?

Comment: Sorry, just no image with link

Comment: I put up the project on GitHub, the files in question are the Hotel's show and HotelController. https://github.com/tyronestock/SO-query/tree/master/complete

Comment: So from the hotel show view you want to link to the content show view?

Comment: No, in the hotel show view I want to display the images from the associated content table (where the id of hotel = hotelId from content). I am able to upload images to the content table from that same show, I now want to display them there.

Comment: Perfect. Simple and just what I needed. Thank you, I have accepted your answer.